# How Can i disable all windows shortcut keys in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to disable all the windows shortcut keys When my application runs,Please tell me How We can do that in vb.net.Please check my code below.

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.Modifiers = Keys.Alt And e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable and enable CTRL+ALT+DEL on demand (at least, you could. I haven't tried this in Windows 7). Take a look at the link below

**SystemParametersInfo Function**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx

I can see why some people are hesitant to answer this question (and that's why I'm hesitant to post usable lines of code); but I do believe there are legit ways to use this (and clearly, Microsoft agrees because they expose this functionality through their APIs).

I have seen this done in professional/commercial software.

EDIT: I don't know whether or not this approach will disable the other keyboard short-cuts; but it should work for CTRL+ALT+DEL